# Casting types in coq

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, compcert

I have the definition `my_def1`:

```
Require Import compcert.common.Memory.
Require Import compcert.common.Values.
Require Import compcert.lib.Integers.  

Definition my_def1 (vl: list memval) : val :=
 match proj_bytes vl with
    | Some bl => Vint(Int.sign_ext 16 (Int.repr (decode_int bl)))
    | None => Vundef
 end.
```

I would like to write another definition `my_def2` similar to `my_def1` like below and add an axiom that `proj_bytes vl` always return `Some bl`, So:

```
Definition my_def2 (vl: list memval) : val :=
   Vint(Int.sign_ext 16 (Int.repr (decode_int ((*?*)) )))
end.
```

*My question is how can I complete `my_def2` and write the related `axiom` about `proj_bytes vl`?*

*Or the question is how can I cast from the type `list memval` to  `list byte` [`decode_int` accepts `list byte`]?*

And here is the definition for `memval`:

```
Inductive memval : Type :=
  Undef : memval
 | Byte : byte -> memval
 | Fragment : val -> quantity -> nat -> memval
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two approaches, lets do some preliminaries first:

```
Variable (memval byte : Type).
Variable (proj_bytes : list memval -> option byte).

Inductive val := Vundef | VInt : byte -> val.

Definition my_def1 (vl: list memval) : val :=
 match proj_bytes vl with
    | Some bl => VInt bl
    | None    => Vundef
 end.
```

Then, you could define your axiom as:

```
Axiom pb1 : forall vl , { v | proj_bytes vl = Some v }.
```

You destruct this axiom and rewrite with the inner equality. However, this approach is a bit incovenient as you can guess.

It may be better to pretend to have a default value to destruct proj_bytes:

```
Variable (byte_def : byte).

Definition bsel vl :=
  match proj_bytes vl with
  | Some bl => bl
  | None    => byte_def
  end.

Definition my_def2 (vl: list memval) : val := VInt (bsel vl).

Lemma my_defP vl : my_def1 vl = my_def2 vl.
Proof.
now destruct (pb1 vl) as [b H]; unfold my_def1, my_def2, bsel; rewrite H.
Qed.
```

However, none of the above methods will give you great advances in a proof, thus the real question is what your original purpose was.

Comment: Thanks. About the axiom, I was trying to write it like `Axiom pb1 : forall vl , proj_bytes vl = Some v.` which didn't recognize v. Could you explain more about its logic?

Comment: I mean the logic of the one you wrote.

Comment: `{v | P}` means there exist some `v` such that `P` holds. You could also be finer, as to specify some axiom `not_undefined vl` that rules out undesired cases, then proceed by case analysis.